# Subdomain Session Issue

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I am trying to access session data across multiple wildcard sub domains. I set the session using the following:

```
<?php
session_name("session"); 
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com'); 
session_start();
$_SESSION['mID'] = 192;
?>
```

I set the above session while on `sub1.example.com`. I then go to `sub2.example.com` and use the following code to access the session:

```
<?php
session_name("session"); 
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com'); 
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

But the session is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check the actual `Set-Cookie` header field value?

Comment: If your site is publicly available, you can use web-sniffer.net; otherwise use tools like Firebug or LiveHTTPHeaders for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Worked for me when I have this problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php