# Starting a php $_SESSION on root domain (www) and sharing the session across subdomains

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to set my PHP $_SESSION and have it usable across all subdomains.  This works fine except when trying to retrieve the session from the root domain (**www**).

If I initiate the session while on **www** then it will *not* share with any sub domain.  If I initiate the session while on a sub domain it will *not* share with **www**.

I have the session_set_cookie_params (index.php) and session.cookie_domain (php.ini) set correctly to .domain.com

When I echo $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] on **www** I get a string of characters that is different from the string of characters used on all sub domains.  All sub domains have the same value for $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"].

I would like to be able to initiate the session on **www** and be able to use that session on all sub domains as well. Is there any solution to this?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: There's `domain` parameter in `setcookie` - are you explicitly setting that, too?

Comment: Please add you concrete php.ini settings to the question as well as the call and data for `session_set_cookie_params`. That "code" is missing. Also I think this question has been asked earlier, probably this is: [Subdomain Session Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458559/subdomain-session-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a name for the session

> session_name("domain");

before setting the session cookie parameters.

```
session_name("domain");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

Comment: Why do you name the session “domain”?

Comment: And why do you suggest that to try? What is the reasoning to try that?

Comment: @Gumbo: you can name it anything.

Comment: @hakra: because i had ran into a similar problem few months ago.

Comment: @MWC Renaming the session shouldn’t have any effect on this issue. It’s the cookie’s domain.

Comment: @Gumbo: I am not asking to rename the session. Just set a name for the session.

Comment: @MWC There is already a [default name for PHP’s sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name): `PHPSESSID.`

Comment: @Gumbo [http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#104678](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#104678)

Comment: @MWC So what? The linked comment just says that session cookie settings do not effect cookies set by `setcookie`.

Comment: @Gumbo I don't know what the actual issue might be. But, setting the session_name fixes the issue.